# .Net Core 2.1 - cannot connect to database on Mac

Tags: .net, macos, ssl, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am developing web application on my Mac. Locally app uses Sql Server database which is installed on my docker and it works like a charm). Today I tried to do first publish on production, so I created database on my hosting service and can't connect to it. I tried to do it thought my backend application, .net cli, Sql Operations Studio, JetBrains DataGrip and always getting this message:

From .net cli or Sql Operations Studio:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)

From JetBrains DataGrip:

> Connection to ******* failed. [08S01] The driver could not establish a
>   secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
>   encryption. Error: "java.security.cert.CertificateException:
>   Certificates do not conform to algorithm constraints".
>   ClientConnectionId:244eb649-282c-4e77-bf8d-052888e814e0

I tried also using different types of SQL Operations Studio release versions:

https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/releases/tag/0.28.4

https://github.com/Microsoft/sqlopsstudio/releases/tag/0.33.1

But it didn't help. I am using MacOS High Sierra
[image]

Comment: Who's your hosting provider? I believe the hosting provider should provide a connection string to use in your app. If you are trying to connect to the contain from your local machine, make sure to double check that your IP address is whitelisted.

Comment: @clenard I wrote to support and they tried to connect to their servers from macOS High Sierra and they have the same problem. But If you try to connect to their servers from windows machine it works without any issue. It looks like some problem with macOS and I don't have any idea how to solve this issue. Strange thing that it was issued on Sql Operation Studio and .net core and it looks like fixed but it' not.